# Javascript error on "Share this on Twitter" page

Tags: twitter, sharethis

I have noticed a Javascript error in IE off of everyone's "Tweet this" button.  I mean, everyone has the problem - and it occurs on twitter's popup window.

To reproduce, find a site with "Tweet this" button: http://cavekitchen.com is an example - with sharing buttons at the end of blog posts.  Click "t".  A popup window shows, asking you to log in -  with a javascript error.  I have not found any sites that failed to have the problem.

Does twitter know? Is there anything we can do as developers to get around it?

Thanks!
Kate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is not inhibiting any functionality, I would not worry about it. It is probably a feature unsupported in IE.